# getting an error when trying use a varibale from one file as an input to a function in a different file

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, traceback

i have this code in one file that is meant to pass the score_list variable to the run_game_over() in a seperate file Game_Over_Screen

```
from Game_Over_Screen import game_over
```

leaderboard = True

```
from Game_Over_Screen import game_over
leaderboard = True

while leaderboard:
    print(score_list)
    game_over.run_game_over(score_list)
    leaderboard = False
    running = False
```

```
this is the run_game_over() function
```

```
class game_over(Buttons, ellipse_button):
    def run_game_over(self, score_list):
        self.go_animation()
        pygame.display.flip()
        global game_over
        game_over = True
        while game_over:
            Buttons.mouse_position(quit_icon)
            Buttons.mouseclick(quit_icon)
            Buttons.mouse_position(play_again_icon)
            Buttons.mouseclick(play_again_icon)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                pass
```

however when i run it i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matty\Documents\Programming Project\uno-1130\uno\src\Start.py", line 35, in <module>
    game_over.run_game_over(score_list)
TypeError: run_game_over() missing 1 required positional argument: 'score_list'
```

Im not sure why this isnt working as i thought id set it up for the score_list variable to be an input correctly but clearly that is not the case

Comment: `game_over` is a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). You have to create an [instance object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of the class

Comment: `game_over` is not a function. It's a class. In your main file you cannot directly do `game_over.run_game_over(score_list)`. Instead you have to first instantiate the class into a variable, then call the method `run_game_over` . I'd suggest you make the class name capitalized to comply with PEP.